# how do I resize my home partition (ext4) on runtime?

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, resize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to resize a ext4 root partition a runtime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-to-resize-a-ext4-root-partition-a-runtime)

I am using ubuntu 11.04. I have installed GParted.

I wanted to resize my home folder cuz its low in free space but GParted wont allow me to resize root and home folder, alothough I can resize other partitions.

Is there any way around to resize during runtime or do I have to use live CD for that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't resize home and root partition, because they are mounted. You have to use live cd.

Comment: Sure you can; just log in directly as root and `umount /home` first.  (More devious techniques, like logging into a terminal as a user but then changing working directory, might also be possible.)

Comment: @SamB: You're right. This question is 2 years old and I probably didn't have so much experiences with Linux back then to think of that.