# ubuntu 16.04 running out of space and VirtualBox vdi not extending automatically

Tags: virtualbox, disk-usage

I am updating my ubuntu 16.04 on VirtualBox 5.1.20 on windows 10 x64 host.
When I have created this machine I checked the 'allocate dynamically' vdi disk.

For some reason I am running out of space and the drive isn't extended automatically, any ideas?

Comment: The VDI will only grow to the maximum size you gave it on creation - how much did you assign there? To increas its size see https://askubuntu.com/questions/248189/why-does-virtualbox-virtual-disk-not-grow-automatically and https://askubuntu.com/questions/251527/virtualbox-drive-does-not-expand-automatically for how to partition it afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I have assigned 8GB as the default suggested. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I increase the hard disk size of the virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only ever used Virtualbox on Windows but assume that it works in a similar way. 
When you create your vdi in the first instance it asks what size it should be, defaulting to 8GB iirc. This is the maximum size that the vdi will expand to. You are choosing whether to just block out the 8GB from the start or whether to expand to 8GB as you need it.

If you fill up that space then you will need to expand it. 
Again, I have only ever done this on Windows but a quick search shows up a bunch of answers...may be this could be of help to you (even if it is a bit old)?

[How do I increase the hard disk size of the virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88647/how-do-i-increase-the-hard-disk-size-of-the-virtual-machine)

EDIT
Sorry, just re-read that it is a Windows host, try this instead.

http://derekmolloy.ie/resize-a-virtualbox-disk/