# How do I partition a hard drive when Ubuntu is already installed?

Tags: partitioning

I installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and now I want to partition my hard drive, but I'm not sure how to partition after Ubuntu is already installed.

How can I partition my hard drive?

Comment: @Braiam I don't think OP is asking about a good partitioning scheme, but about how partitioning a hard drive with an OS already installed actually works and is done.

Answer (score 1):

Try GParted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
sudo gparted
```

it's pretty self-explanatory

Answer (score 0):

Go to ubuntu software center and install an app called Gparted...or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `sudo apt-get install gparted` ...which is an app that partitions hard disks.

Answer (score 0):

How did you install your Ubuntu system?

If you installed with root and home partition, you will have to unmount the home partition and shrink it. Then format the new free space, or install something onto it.

If you installed with only root partition, you can shrink it at run time using fdisk, but that is a complicated task. I would recommend creating a bootable USB or Live DVD, boot into the USB/DVD and resize the installed partition from the "out side".

The third answer here shows how to do the complicated way, at run time:

[Ask Ubuntu: How to resize a ext4 root partition at run time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-to-resize-a-ext4-root-partition-at-runtime)