# How to reinstall Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, windows-7, gparted, macosx

First, here's what happened: I had OS X Mavericks (10.9) installed on my MacBook Pro. Then I wiped the operating system to get Windows 7 instead. After that, I went to install Ubuntu 12.04, but while installing, it wiped Windows 7 as well. Now I'm looking to reinstall Mac OS X, but I can't edit the partitions to create unallocated space, because it is stored in the ext4 partiton, mounted at "/". Any help would be appreciated.

*edit*: when I try to boot from any device (disk/USB/SD) this message shows up twice [error: efidisk read error.]

Comment: You need to ask this on [The apple Q&A](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) not Ubuntu, as your current problem is with OSX.

Comment: Actually, the problem *IS* with Ubuntu, because the need is to resize the *Ubuntu* partition. That said, the question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime) (and probably many others).

Answer (score 1):

To create unallocated space, take your installation drive for Ubuntu, and click `Try Ubuntu without installing` from the GRUB Startup menu. Once logged in, look for GParted in the Ubuntu search menu. Once opened, select your Ubuntu partition, right-click it, then click "Resize" from the menu. Resize to the desired size, then install Maverick in the unallocated space.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but whenever I load from the installation drive, I only have these options: Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-24-generic; Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-24-generic (recovery mode); Previous Linux Versions (Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-15-generic; Ubuntu, with Linux 3.11.0-15-generic (recovery mode)); Memory test (memtest86+); Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Comment: Do that first one.