# What is the best partitioning tool for Hitachi 160 GB HDD for a Ubuntu Installation

Tags: partitioning, acer

I am currently using a Acer Aspire 4810TZ-4696 which has a HDD from Hitachi with a capacity of 160Gb

(/dev/sda1=157Gb Ext4(vers.1.0)

Mounted on file system root

- (/dev/sda2=3,1Gb extnded part.)
- (/dev/sda5=3,1Gb Linux swap (vers.2)—Active)

What is best partitioning/resizing tool for installed Ubuntu on an Hitachi 160 GB HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partitioning tools for Ubuntu are not hardware dependen, they word the same on any drive. gparted will do the job.

Please keep in mind, that you can not make changes to partitions that are in use (mounted). If you want to manage the partition you are running Ubuntu from, you have to boot from a Ubuntu live CD / DVD / USB drive. They usually include gparted in the live desktop environment.

Comment: I think you can grow mounted ext4 partitions via gParted. Source: http://askubuntu.com/a/109360/371765