# Why can't I use my unllocated disk space?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-management

I want to increase my `/home` partition size and merge in the unallocated disk space. How can I do this please?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: can you tell me the maximum number of primary partitions allowed on a disk and how many you have? :)

Comment: Which of those is your /home partition?

Comment: He does not seem to have a specific `/home` partition.  Maybe the recommendation should be to have the unallocated space made into the `/home`.  However, the OP would need help to move the current user files from where they currently reside to the new location of `/ home`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

You can't increase the space because they are mounted, in use. To increase that space you must boot into a live GParted session from a bootable USB or disk. I hope that helped.

Comment: According to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime/109360#109360  it can be done without login out.  I agree with @Arynn though that it best to do it booting from a live USB.  Make sure you backup all your files before though.

Answer (score 0):

Your home partition `sda5` is part of the extended partition `sda3`. You can only increase your root partition `sda5` by 3.86 GiB.

The only way I see is to move your `sda5` out of the extended partition `sda3`.

I would recommend to back up your disk first before doing anything.