# Resize root partition or use another?

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk-usage

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 16.04. I've created a two partitions before installing Ubuntu. One is 40 GB (nr. 3) and second is about 150 GB (nr. 2). I thought that 40GB is for Ubuntu installation enough because I didn't know that many things are installed to this partition.

So now I have a problem. When I install for example `Bytecoin` wallet, there is `~/.bytecoin/` created which takes a lot of disk space. Many other programs uses this partition and I don't have a disk space anymore there.

[image]

I could resize partition 2 to for example 35 GB and then resize 3 to 138 GB but I'm not sure if it's safe since the root is on partition 3.

I can just click on the partition and resize it.

Is it save? Or do you have another way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

Partition 1 is used by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize the root partition like described [in this SO answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/24027/51957).

But another, maybe easier way is:
Create a new partition and create a symlink to it. In your case

> resize partition 2 to for example 35 GB

and create a new partition in the free space, e.g. named `/dev/sda9`. Then format it with ext4, create a directory `bytecoin/` on it and move all data from `~/.bytecoin/` on your old partition to `bytecoin/` on the new partition. Finally remove the old folder and create a soft-link in its place

```
ln -s /dev/sda9/bytecoin ~/.bytecoin/
```

The philosophy behind this is to differentiate programs from data.