# Extend size of Ubuntu on Flash

Tags: resize

Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS was installed on 64GB flash disk.

When boot for that flash disk and check the size of the partition, it is only 6.4 GB.

What is the procedure to follow so could use all the disk?

Comment: I think you might need to look into a persistent storage partition...

Comment: Assuming you have already setup persistence, check out `gparted`. There are lots of examples in **Ask Ubuntu** but here is one of them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime/119458#119458