# I am using an Azure VM and just wanted to resize the main drive /dev/root filesystem, will there be any issues if I'm gonna do it in AZ Portal only?

Tags: 20.04, azure

Wanted to resize the main drive /dev/root from for example OSDisk Size 16Gib to 32Gib. Do I need configuration inside the VM (via SSH) after doing the OSDisk resizing in the Azure Portal?

Thank you

Comment: That will only increase the disk size. You still need to resize the partition and the filesystem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resize an ext root partition at runtime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime)

Comment: Are you also referring to OSDisk space? With regards to datadisk I knew how to extend it. However in OSDisk I still don't have any exp. Do I still need to resize filesystem too?